# Calibri (Body) font-family in HTML & Microsoft Word files in Java application

Tags: java, html, fonts, ms-word, struts

I need to develop a Microsoft Word file with Calibri (Body) font-family. This document will be downloaded through my application on a button click. We're not using the Apache POI due to some usage policy in company. What I've done is added the font-family as Calibri and sans serif in the HTML tags like `<p> </p>` and send the `response.setContentType` as application/word from the Java application. The files gets downloaded as MS Word file but the font family doesnt come as Calibri (Body).

How to get the Calibri (Body) font family in HTML?

Comment: You're asking how to download an HTML page and pretend it's a Word document?

Comment: no...we want to give the feature to download the word file. Since we haven't used any jar for generating the word file. the code is written in html file. Now user wants calibri (body) but that isn't getting generated in word file. its only calibri. My question is how to use calibri (body)  font in html

Comment: I think you may need to do some basic research into the topic of ***Themes*** and how theme settings pre-set properties (especially fonts) and affect styles in Word documents. Calibri (body) is *not a font*, only Calibri is a font. The (body) part comes from the theme settings. It's not clear why the user feels the two are not the same - whether they're bothered by the difference in the name, or if there's some other problem. You need to clarify exactly why the requirement is needed.

Comment: FWIW you could *try* saving a simple Word document that has this in it to a "web page" (full, Word round-trip HTML) then inspect that HTML to perhaps be able to see how Word generates the information. Other than that, the document would need to be generated using Word Open XML (using a tool such as Apache POI, for example).